# Getting the topic of a channel in a twisted IRC bot

Tags: python, twisted, irc

I am having trouble getting the topic of a channel using the twisted irc framework. My bot joins one channel and I want it to be able to query the topic of another channel. I send a LIST message using `topic('#channelname)` and I thought I would get the response by overriding the `topicUpdated()` method, but that isn't getting called. I also tried overriding `irc_RPL_TOPIC()` but that isn't getting called either. Yes the channel exists, yes it has a topic, and yes I can get the topic using raw sockets.

What is the proper way to get the topic of a channel using `twisted.words.protocols.irc`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RFC 1459 [states](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1459#section-6.2) that when using LIST, each channel and its topic are sent with the numeric 332 (aka. RPL_LIST).

I don't know how Twisted works, but you should be able to get them with a method named `irc_RPL_LIST`, `irc_332`, or something similar.